# Skipping the "ATE1 E0" probing when loading the ACM driver on Linux

Tags: serial-port

We're using Yocto to build an embedded arm distribution. It creates a composite USB device - USB + ETH + ACM. On boot, the serial driver spends 10-15 seconds sending:

```
         "ATE1 E0\rATE1 E0\rATE1 E0\r~\r~\r"
```

to the the serial port (/dev/ttyGS0), then allows connections. I assume it is probing to see if the serial port is a modem. I'm looking for a way to tell the driver that the port is not a modem and it can skip the probe.

I see references to the "ATE1 E0" command being sent by modemmanager, but there is no modemmanager on our system and I don't see anything that looks ike it replaces it.

```
# pwd
/sys/kernel/config/usb_gadget/g1

# uname -srm
Linux 4.14.164

# head b*
==> bDeviceClass <==
0xef

==> bDeviceProtocol <==
0x01

==> bDeviceSubClass <==
0x02

==> bMaxPacketSize0 <==
0x40

==> bcdDevice <==
0x0414

==> bcdUSB <==
0x0200

# ls functions/
acm.GS0  ffs.ffs_usb  ncm.usb0
```